# Printing and counting unique values from an .xlsx file

Tags: python, excel

I'm fairly new to Python and still learning the ropes, so I need help with a step by step program without using any functions. I understand how to count through an unknown column range and output the quantity. However, for this program, I'm trying to loop through a column, picking out unique numbers and counting its frequency.

So I have an excel file with random numbers down column A. I only put in 20 numbers but let's pretend the range is unknown. How would I go about extracting the unique numbers and inputting them into a separate column along with how many times they appeared in the list?

I'm not really sure how to go about this. :/

```
unique = 1
    while xw.Range((unique,1)).value != None:
        frequency = 0
        if unique != unique: break
        quantity += 1
    "end"
```

Answer (score 0):

Using pandas library would be the easiest way to do. I created a sample excel sheet having only one column called "Random_num"

```
import pandas

data = pandas.read_excel("sample.xlsx", sheet_name = "Sheet1")
print(data.head()) # This would give you a sneak peek of your data

print(data['Random_num'].value_counts()) # This would solve the problem you asked for
# Make sure to pass your column name within the quotation marks 
#eg: data['your_column'].value_counts()
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I presume as you can't use functions this may be homework...so, high level:

You could first go through the column and then put all the values in a list?

Secondly take the first value from the list and go through the rest of the list - is it in there? If so then it is not unique. Now remove the value where you have found the duplicate from the list. Keep going if you find another remove that too.

Take the second value and so on?

You would just need list comprehension, some loops and perhaps .pop()